# How to send arguments from dialplan to Perl subroutines AGI and send respectives returns back to dialplan

Tags: perl, asterisk, agi

I'm using Asterisk :: AGI module to interact with Asterisk 1.8, but I did not see samples to use perl subroutines. I want to connect with a web service and organize the AGI better, would be a good idea to use subroutines instead to do all the code inside if-else block, sending args from dialplan and get the return of theses subroutines.

I know about get and set variables with this module but I want to know if there is something like this:

```
use Asterisk::AGI;

my $AGI = new Asterisk::AGI;

sub some_subroutine {

    my ($param1, $param2, param3) = @ARGV;

    # do something with parameters

    $agi_data = something_done_with_parameters;

    return $AGI->set_variable("agi_data", $agi_data);
}
```

In dialplan context:

```
[simple_interact]
exten = s,1,AGI(script.pl, some_subroutine, param1, param2, param3)
 same = n,NoOp(${agi_data})
```

Comment: okay, and what is question?

Comment: @arheops Is there a way to use Perl AGI module sending parameters to functions from dialplan and return values back dialplan? I don't know how to use subroutines in perl AGI.

Comment: Sure. There are alot of examples availible online. Is that all you want to know?

Comment: @arheops Yes, just that. I just can find Perl AGI with conditional statements not using functions receiving parameters from dialplan. Can you show me some of these samples?

Comment: Wait. So are you asking now how to use functions inside perl script? It is usual way and described in every and each book about perl.

Comment: @arheops Really that a perl book teaches about perl functions? I was waiting for this clarification! No, I'm ask how to send parameters from dial plan and setting the return back to dial plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that doesn't has how to call one function passing the name of function as argument natively. So, one of the ways that I found  to work with AGI, with Perl o PHP, was instead of has a file with various functions, we must to define a function to generate dynamic calls to theses functions passing the identifier of function and the parameters  needed via dialplan.